# Using aliases in bash scripts

Tags: bash, alias

I have a bash file with a number of functions, which I source from my `.bashrc`.
Have a print_text function to print some text to which I associate an alias `ptx`.
The alias is used in a number of functions (e.g. `func2`, `func3`, ...).  At the end,
I use func_alias to set my aliases and call `func_alias`.

Looks like I cannot use `ptx` in `func2`, `func3`, ... as things are.

What would be a neat way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

print_text ()
{
  ...
}

export -f print_text

func2 ()
{
  ptx ...
  ...
}

export -f func2

func3 ()
{
  ptx ...
  ...
}

export -f func3

func_alias ()
{
  alias ptx=print_text
}

export -f func_alias

func_alias
```

Comment: write ptx as a function instead of an alias.

Comment: Very good idea,  Felicitations @cas.

Comment: Like this?  ptx () { print_text "$@" } export -f ptx

Comment: whatever your `ptx` alias does, rewrite it as a function. and yeah, you'll need to explicitly use "$@" to do anything with the args in the function (this is not necessary with an alias because an alias is just a simple thing and the shell just replaces its name with whatever it's definition).   If the function needs to be used in a sub-shell, then export it.  if not, you don't need to.